# How can HttpClient 4.5 be configured to parse cookies as part of a 401 auth negotiation?

Tags: java, http, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am attempting to use a password protected restful service using httpclient.  The request order is:

```
client -> server CONNECT
server <- client 200 Connection established
client -> server POST
server <- client 401 Authorization Required
client -> server POST (with Authorization header added)
```

I have some httpclient 3 sample code which I can see processes the cookies after recieving the 401 response, accepts cookies and sends them back with the second POST request, however in httpclient 4 these cookies are ignored.  Looking at the source code it seems that `MainClientExec#execute` should process the response headers and modify the request when it removes the `AUTH.WWW_AUTH_RESP` and `AUTH.PROXY_AUTH_RESP` headers.

Ignoring the question of whether the server is behaving properly or not is there any way to make this work out of the box?  I'm reluctant to use a legacy version of httpclient.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/eveoh/ews-java-api/commit/c6f54bb9665c3b714e41ad43ebe31527f77b59fe

Comment: This almost works, but it seems that despite `CookieProcessingTargetAuthenticationStrategy` being called after the 401 is received the request on line 40 is the initial CONNECT not the subsequent POST

Comment: Proxy auth is managed by a separate proxy auth strategy

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something, in the debugger I can setup up 3 frames into MainClientExec and request#getMethod = POST while context#getRequest#getRequestLine#getMethod = CONNECT